# Jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Before writing any jquery they always recommend us using

```
$( document ).ready(function() {});
```

and place all our code within this function, but I noticed certain tutorial use this instead

```
(function($){})(jQuery)
```

and

```
(function($){}(jQuery));
```

what is the difference actually?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd snippets result in the same behavior (the expression are parsed equivalently, although the last `;` may result in ASI interactions) and are also known as IIFE's (hint: search terms) or Immediately Invoked Function Expressions.

Comment: Apart from what mentioned below you can also check this http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/22/function%E2%80%A6-vs-function%E2%80%A6-or-domready-vs-the-module-pattern/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() { YOUR CODE });
```

1. This code wraps `YOUR CODE` in jQuery's on document ready handler. This makes sure all the HTML is loaded before you start running your script. Also, since `YOUR CODE` is part of an anonymous function (a closure), this keeps your global scope clean.

...

```
$(function(){ YOUR CODE });
```

2. This is the same thing as #1, just using shorthand.

...

```
(function($){ YOUR CODE })(jQuery)
```

3. This does *not* wrap anything in an on ready handler, so it'll run *immediately*, without regard to what HTML has been loaded so far. However, it *does* wrap `YOUR CODE` in an anonymous function, where you'll be able to reference the jQuery object with `$`.

...

```
(function($){ YOUR CODE }(jQuery));
```

4. This is the same thing as #3.

Comment: +1 for being closest to correct, except that "wraps YOUR CODE around jQuery's on document ready handler." should be "calls your code when the *document.ready* event, or if not available when the *window.onload* event, occurs".

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {//when document is read
```

And

```
$(function() {
```

are the same thing, the second is just short hand

You can also do

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

//The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.

```
(function($){})(jQuery)
```

is an Self-Executing Anonymous Function

So basically it’s an anonymous function that lets jQuery play nicely with other javascript libraries that might have $ variable/function. Also if you notice, all jQuery plugins code is wrapped in this anonymous function.

Comment: The OP doesn't even mention `$(function () {});`. And it should probably be explained that the `$(document).ready(function () {});` does not execute immediately (necessarily) - it waits for the DOM to be ready. The `(function($){})(jQuery)` executes immediately

Comment: Ian I hope the OP realizes that Document Dot Ready means Document ready.

Answer (score 0):

The first one makes the method run on `document` `ready`. Read more [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
(function($){/*Your code*/})(jQuery)
```

The last two **encapsulate** variable / function declarations in your code to a local scope, that gets as a prameter the jQuery object. This approach is used for not littering the global scope with declarations,ie localizing variables.

The difference between the last two is just that the first one delimits function with an extra set of parentheses, to make it visually more clear.

Basically this is how **modules** are constructed in javascript and making sure one block of code doesn't affect the other.

For more information here's a **[good article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)** about js development patterns.

Example:

```
var f = function (str) {
   window.alert(str);
};

var name = "John Doe";

f();
```

Functionally is the same as

```
(function (w) {
    var f = function (str) {
       w.alert(str);
    };

    var name = "John Doe";

    f();
})(window);
```

And as you can see, the first one creates variables in the global scope, that might affect other scripts, while the second one does everything locally. 
Moreover in the second example I did rename the reference to `window`, and made it available for the method through `w`. The same happens in your example as well.

Imagine having two js libraries that both use the **alias** shorthand `$`. You wouldn't know in your code where, which gets referenced. While on the other hand `jQuery` always references the `jQuery` library. And in your case the last two methods just make sure that `$` is just a renamed `jQuery` object, and not anything else coming from another library.

Comment: There is no function declaration in the OP, only *FunctionExpression*. There is no functional difference between the last two. The difference between 1 and the others is that in the first, *$* is assumed to be the jQuery object, in the second and third it is passed as a parameter so that within the function expressions, *$* is a reference to the jQuery object.

Comment: I wanted to refer to functions / variables declared in the code that is put inside the anon function. Cleared it up

Answer (score 0):

The first one is executing the function as soon as the document is *ready* while the others are IIFE's that ensures jQuery can be accessed via it's alias sign `$` within that function :

```
var $ = 'other plugin';
(function($){
    alert($); // jQuery here
})(jQuery);
```